# Deleting Zeros from Numpy Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a question regarding the deletion from arrays. I have a 3-D numpy array (coordinates are z,y,x) with an estimated 900^3 size. Only a few values are nonzero, but they have a nontrivial spatial distribution. I want to delete all 2-D slices in that array which have only zeros in it. In other words, I want an array with minimum size which still has all relevant data in it.

My attempt looks like:

```
    while np.all(a[0]==0):
        a=np.delete(a,0,0)
    while np.all(a[a.shape[0]-1]==0) and a.shape[0]>1:
        a=np.delete(a,-1,0)
```

and seems to work for the z-direction. How can I do something equal in the other two directions? And is there maybe another way of doing it better?

Another Idea was

```
tmp=np.delete(tmp,np.all(tmp==0,axis=1),1)
```

but that one seems to work only from the start and leaves out the zeros at the end.

Is it maybe possible, to rotate an array in 3D space?

Comment: If you want to rotate the array in 3d space, you can use numpy.roll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to rearrange your axes, but it sounds like you might really be looking for a [sparse array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean by this. Sparse arrays are 2D or not?

Comment: In scipy, yes...good point.  I'll leave it in my answer just in case it might help someone with a 2D problem.  People have implemented multidimensional sparse arrays, which might be good depending on what exactly you need to do with the points afterward, if you check this out for example: http://www.janeriksolem.net/2010/02/sparray-sparse-n-dimensional-arrays-in.html.  But if your code works for the z-direction, why not just transpose to rotate the dimensions twice to repeat the process, then once more to get back to the original order?

Comment: Actually yes, that works. Might still look like magic to me, but actually it does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun problem, here is what I came up with:

```
for ax in range(3):
    all_but_ax = [i for i in range(3) if i != ax]
    a = delete(a, where(apply_over_axes(sum, abs(a), all_but_ax).ravel() == 0), 
                  ax)
```

So you some the `abs(a)` over all but the current axis == current 2D slice, and check if it is zero, which means it is empty. The `where` gives the indices for the delete.